# Bit compressed structure

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

I am currently working on project, where I need to store quite large number (~units of billions) of structures in vector. I also need to iterate over that vector in linear manner, so the less data I have to go through, the better.

Therefore I naturally started to optimize the size of single structure. If, for example, I have multiple bool values, I can store the true/false value in single bit and compress all the bool values into one char/16-bit, whatever has sufficient size. For some of the entries I need only 20-bit unsigned integer. Therefore I can again compress these values.

I then end-up with something like this (note that this is only simplified example):

```
class Foo {
private:
    uint32_t m_time;
    uint32_t m_comb;

public:
    Foo(uint32_t t, uint32_t big, uint16_t small, bool is_blue, bool is_nice)
        : m_time(t), m_comb((big << 12) | (small << 2) | (is_blue << 1) | is_nice)
    { }

    uint32_t get_time()  const { return m_time; }
    uint32_t get_big()   const { return m_comb >> 12; }
    uint16_t get_small() const { return m_comb & 0b11111111100; }
    uint16_t is_blue()   const { return m_comb & 0b10; }
    uint16_t is_nice()   const { return m_comb & 0b1; }
};
```

The question is, can this be somehow automated using templates? My idea was that I would insert the order of entries, required bit size and than I would be able to call `get<i>()` which would return me the i-th entry of structure. My motivation is to get rid of writing the code manually since tickling bits seems to me quite error-prone. I tried to implement this my self but failed hopelessly.

Comment: For some of that, you could use [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), for other bits perhaps [`bitset`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).  People also sometimes use `enum`s with power-of-two enumerations ORed together.  I suggest exploring those and seeing if whatever's left is worth diving into templates for.

Comment: Wow, never heard of bit fields! Definitely going to look into that.

Comment: "I also need to iterate over that vector in linear manner, so the less data I have to go through, the better." - Also consider refactoring `array of structs` into `struct of arrays`, so to say: for every field, use its own container, and optimize the container correspondingly. That helps to optimize data cache usage, in case if you need to scan this *array* for a particular value in the field. That would also allow to use the `ffs()` to search inside one-bit field array.

Comment: @Dummy00001, 20- and 10-bit integers would require custom array specializations in this case.

Comment: @bipll, yes they would. And that's the advantage - if you need to scale the data structure to gazillion of items. Not only you can account for every bit, you could also speculatively employ sparse structures, to avoid huge chunks of zeros wasting memory. Also, that allows to employ another trick: turn the data presentation around, from `index -> value` to `value -> set of indexes`. Much more work, but if memory consumption/access is the priority - it's worth it.

Comment: My data are quite unique, so this wouldn't help very much. Plus when Iterate over the vector, I use all the data, not only some of it. Therefore I presume that storing all the data in one vector is more beneficial in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this very easily with **[bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)**.

```
class Foo {
private:
    uint32_t m_time;
    uint32_t m_big : 20;
    uint32_t m_small : 10;
    uint32_t m_isblue : 1;
    uint32_t m_isnice : 1;
public:
    Foo(uint32_t t, uint32_t big, uint16_t small, bool is_blue, bool is_nice)
        : m_time(t), m_big(big), m_small(small), m_isblue(is_blue), m_isnice(is_nice)
    { }

    uint32_t get_time()  const { return m_time; }
    uint32_t get_big()   const { return m_big; }
    uint16_t get_small() const { return m_small; }
    uint16_t is_blue()   const { return m_isblue; }
    uint16_t is_nice()   const { return m_isnice; }
};
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/lpmD4N) showing size.

**Edit: additional infos**

To summarize the comments, the way the compiler packs the bit fields together is implementation dependent:

> **9.6/1** (...) Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is
>   implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable
>   allocation unit. [Note: Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some
>   machines and not on others. Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on
>   some machines, left-to-right on others. —end note ]

So you have no guarantee, but compilers usually do there best to put them together. As a rule of a thumb, as long as your bit fields are consecutive and their total bits smaller than the base type you are using, there are big chances that the packing will be optimal. If needed you could fine tune the base type, as [this online demo](http://ideone.com/zhCcut) shows.

Comment: Nice. Can I assume, that this will generally store the bits without any gaps? Consider for example I will define I want 8x `uint32_t some_names :20`, will this only occupy 20 bytes?

Comment: @Jendas. Unfortunately, no. The fields will fill up an `uint32_t`, but when add more than a single element can hold, it start a new one. In other words, a bit field can't stretch between two `uint32_t` elements.

Comment: That is unfortunate. But quite understandable. It would be nice to have some solution that does that though.

Comment: @Jendas the standard states "* Allocation of bit-fields within a class
object is implementation-defined*".  So you have no formal guarantee, but usually, the compilers pack them as expected (with padding for the unused bits, as noted by Lindydancer). After all this feature is designed for optimizing use of memory in a time were memory was scarce.

Comment: Please pay attention on [this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field): everything about the actual allocation details of bit fields within the class object is `implementation-defined`. So you don't have to store it for other programs.

Comment: @Jendas this [online demo](http://ideone.com/zhCcut) will interest you:  using `uint64_t` as base type for your 20 bits allow indeed to pack them on 20 bytes with gcc.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the idea of how this thing works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since bit field are `implementation-defined` I've decided to write the bit read/write functions. It would comes in handy when you want to store data (cache or something) on disk.

Here is source code simulation [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5a80f4feffc95b40).

```
#include <iostream>

bool GetBit(uint32_t num, uint8_t pos)
{
    //check pos < sizeof(num)*8
    return (num >> pos) & 0x1;
}

uint8_t GetByte(uint32_t num, uint8_t pos)
{
    //check pos < sizeof(num)*8
    return (num >> pos) & 0xFF;    
}

uint16_t GetShort(uint32_t num, uint8_t pos)
{
    //check pos < sizeof(num)*8
    return (num >> pos) & 0xFFFF;    
}

uint32_t SetBit(bool val, uint32_t &dest, uint8_t pos)
{
    dest ^= (-val ^ dest) & (1 << pos);
    return dest;
}

uint32_t SetByte(uint8_t val, uint32_t &dest, uint8_t pos)
{
    dest &= ~(0xFF<<pos); //clean
    dest |= val<<pos; //set
    return dest;
}

uint32_t SetShort(uint16_t val, uint32_t &dest, uint8_t pos)
{
    dest &= ~(0xFFFF<<pos); //clean
    dest |= val<<pos; //set
    return dest;
}

void PrintBin(uint32_t s, const char* pszComment)
{
    std::cout << pszComment << ": " << std::endl;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < sizeof(s) * 8; n++)
        std::cout << GetBit(s, n) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t s = 4294967295; //all bits
    PrintBin(s, "Start");

    SetBit(false, s, 2); 
    PrintBin(s, "Set bit 2 to FALSE");

    SetByte(0, s, 22);
    PrintBin(s, "Set byte 22 to val 0");

    SetByte(30, s, 22);
    PrintBin(s, "Set byte 22 to val 30");

    SetShort(0, s, 4);
    PrintBin(s, "Set short 4 to val 0");

    SetShort(65000, s, 4);
    PrintBin(s, "Set short 4 to val 65000");

    std::cout << "byte at 22 = " << (int)GetByte(s, 22) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "short at 4 = " << (int)GetShort(s, 4) << std::endl;    
}
```

Output:

```
Start: 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
Set bit 2 to FALSE: 
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
Set byte 22 to val 0: 
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
Set byte 22 to val 30: 
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
Set short 4 to val 0: 
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
Set short 4 to val 65000: 
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
byte at 22 = 30
short at 4 = 65000
```

You can convert these functions into `#DEFINE`s and add range checking in debug mode.